# GTK3 add to a window's task tray icon context menu

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk

I'm working in C, and create a window, and a menu:

```
window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
[ ... ]
menu = gtk_menu_new();
```

I currently have the menu connected to a button in the window like so:

```
g_signal_connect (widget, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (open_menu), NULL);
```

However the menu is literally the only interface it needs. On windows I have a tray icon with a context menu.

I don't want to use GtkStatusIcon because it is deprecated, and because it would be a misuse of them.

I'd like to do something similar on Linux, but I need to be able to get the window's task tray icon context menu.

Is this possible? Or is the fact that not all Linux versions have a taskbar make this a bad idea?

Any alternative solutions I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every desktop environment on Linux has a slightly different design goal when it comes to this. Gnome is moving away from tray icons and prefers the design of DBus activated services and Notifications. Unity/Plasma has AppIndicators which largely function like tray icons but are slightly more limited since they are DBus interfaces. And classic environments like XFCE are still X11 only so XEmbed style trays (GtkStatusIcon) are still in heavy use.